# I pictured [him], working hard - Why the comma?

Tags: punctuation, supplementation

> I pictured that handsome stripling in the factory, **working hard**. This made her horny.
>   (Days at the Factory)

Why is there a comma? I think this structure is "picture object doing something" but this comma divides this sentence, making this "working" look like part of a present participle construction.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct: *working hard* is an object complement.

The comma is the author's way of indicating the flow of thought: first the narrator  imagines the boy in the factory, and then 'supplements' this fantasy with the additional detail that he is working hard.

Comment: But it could also be interpreted that this comma is just a marker to make it clear that working hard modifies the stripling, because in the factory is between the two. Just for clarity.?

Comment: @username901345 No: it would require a quite exceptional context for *working hard* to modify anything else.

Comment: I would say this is a bit odd to me, because you picture someone doing something, like this it should flow like that. This doing should not be an appendage or extra info to this man.

Comment: @username901345 It's a *developing* fantasy--the author builds the 'picture' in steps. You might think of it as analogous to a movie script: first you see the boy's face in closeup, with the factory setting in the background, then it pulls out to show the boy in a medium shot and you become aware that he is working hard.